# Responsive banner image for all resolutions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have a banner image, spanning 100% width of the screen
An example of what I want to achieve is found here:

http://www.aha.io/roadmapping/where-aha-fits

Look at it in full screen. The banner is 100% width, and maybe 15% of the screen height.

When you shrink the window size, the banner still uses 100% of the screen width, but seems to crop the left size, I think, and reduced in height, maintaining the screen height of around 15%.

I created a demo of what I am trying to do here:

http://www.bootply.com/Hrxwy8BjTT

What I end up with is, in 'mobile' version, a very very thin banner.

How can I make it crop a bit, and maintain around 10% (in my case) of the screen height (And not creating a scroll bar)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be a good case to use Media Queries.The code below targets specific widths in a mobile-first pattern. This way the style for #background depends on the width of the device.

```
#background {
  background: url(http://snowdebts.com/images/banner-thin.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 225px; width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
    #background { height: 200px; }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #background { height: 150px; }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #background { height: 100px; }
}
```

I took the liberty of removing your image tag, and setting it in CSS instead. So, for your HTML, you need the following:

```
 <div class="tab-content">
   <div id="background">

   </div>
   <div style="padding-left: 20px;">
     Hello
   </div>
</div>
```

You can modify the heights into percentages or fixed widths depending on what you need. Also, since we've set up the image as a background for the div element, we don't need to worry about the scroll bar, just the size of the div.

Comment: Perfect, and educational! Thanks @Brian!

Comment: Pushing my luck, but is there anyway to make the center of the image stay centred, so it crops the left and right? As opposed to cropping the right side?

Comment: Oops wrong answer. Let me look into it. I thought background-position: center fixed it

Comment: So, if by center you meant the coin stack, it's not centered because the original image actually shows the coin on the right hand side. You either want to crop the original image, or use values to move the background image around.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I'll re-jig the image with the main content to be more centred, and that'll be perfect. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Always happy to help. :)